# Return integer parsed in Parser integer >> eof using bind

Tags: parsing, haskell, trifecta

Using the trifecta library, I am supposed to parse an integer string that does not contain trailing letters *and* return the integer parsed:

```
Prelude> parseString (yourFuncHere) mempty "123"
Success 123
Prelude> parseString (yourFuncHere) mempty "123abc"
Failure (interactive):1:4: error: expected: digit,
    end of input
123abc<EOF>
```

I have been able to do this using do notation like so:

```
x <- decimal
eof
return x
```

But I have been unsuccessful in translating this to bind/lambdas.

This does not keep the parsed number, but is correct otherwise:

```
decimal >> eof
```

I guess I should start like this

```
decimal >>= \x -> eof
```

but after this, every permutation I have tried does not work. How do I return the number parsed and check for eof using bind syntax instead of do?

Comment: You should be able to use the Applicative instance rather than the Monad instance: `decimal <* eof`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to do

```
decimal >>= (\x -> (eof >> return x))
```

The `eof` combinator does not return anything, so you have to return the thing you want yourself.

Comment: also `a >> b` is the same as `a >>= (\_ -> b)` in case you need to write it completely with `>>=`

Comment: Thanks. Had never seen a return outside a do block.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat remember that return is just a function in Haskell, there's nothing special about it to the compiler. You can use it as you would any other function.